# Blackjack deck class creationg C#

Tags: c#, debugging

I started creating a black jack game and so far I have created the card class and the deck class. The card class is working fine but when I try to test the deck class the array is filled with "BlackJackLab.Deck" and I'm really confused why..Here is the code I'm using:

```
class Card
{
    public string Suit { get; set; }
    public string Rank { get; set; }

    public Card(string suit, string rank)
    {
        if ((suit != "Hearts" && suit != "Spades" && suit != "Diamonds" && suit != "Clubs") || (
             rank != "Ace" && rank != "1" && rank != "2" && rank != "3" && rank != "4" && rank != "5"
             && rank != "6" && rank != "7" && rank != "8" && rank != "9" && rank != "10" && rank != "Jack" && rank != "Queen" && rank != "King"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error not such suit or rank found. Exiting...");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }
        else
        {
            this.Suit = suit;
            this.Rank = rank;
        }
    }

    public static string[] ValidSuits()
    {
        string[] suits = new string[4];
        suits[0] = "Hearts";
        suits[1] = "Spades";
        suits[2] = "Diamonds";
        suits[3] = "Clubs";

        return suits;
    }

    public static string[] ValidRanks()
    {
        string[] ranks = new string[13];
        ranks[0] = "Ace";
        for (int i = 2; i <= 10; i++)
        {
             ranks[i - 1] = i.ToString();
        }
        ranks[10] = "Jack";
        ranks[11] = "Queen";
        ranks[12] = "King";
        return ranks;
    }

    public int GetValue()
    {
        if (this.Rank.Equals("Ace"))
            return 1;
        else if (this.Rank.Equals("2"))
            return 2;
        else if (this.Rank.Equals("3"))
            return 3;
        else if (this.Rank.Equals("4"))
            return 4;
        else if (this.Rank.Equals("5"))
            return 5;
        else if (this.Rank.Equals("6"))
            return 6;
        else if (this.Rank.Equals("7"))
            return 7;
        else if (this.Rank.Equals("8"))
            return 8;
        else if (this.Rank.Equals("9"))
            return 9;
        else if (this.Rank.Equals("10"))
            return 10;
        else if (this.Rank.Equals("Jack"))
            return 11;
        else if (this.Rank.Equals("Queen"))
            return 12;
        else
            return 13;
    }

    public string GetFace ()
    {
        return string.Format("{0} of {1}", this.Rank, this.Suit);
    }
}

class Deck
{
    public Card[] Cards { get; set; }
    public Random RandomGenerator { get; set; }

    public Deck()
    {
        int i = 0;
        this.Cards = new Card[52];

        foreach (string rank1 in Card.ValidRanks())
        {
            foreach (string suit1 in Card.ValidSuits())
            {
                this.Cards[i] = new Card(suit1, rank1);
                i++;
            }
        }

        this.RandomGenerator = new Random();
    }

    public Card DrawCard()
    {
        int randomNumber;

        do
        {
            randomNumber= RandomGenerator.Next(0, 52);
        }
        while (Cards[randomNumber] == null);

        Card drawnCard = Cards[randomNumber];
        Cards[randomNumber] = null;
        return drawnCard;
    }
}
```

And the code I'm testing it with:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Deck myDeck = new Deck();

        Card myCard = myDeck.DrawCard();
        Console.WriteLine(myCard.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Please help me, I'm really stuck.

Comment: You need to [override the `ToString` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173154.aspx).

Comment: Off topic, but the cards would a good case for using an [enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx). You can give them names, and assign integer values to them, and cast it to int when you need the number.

Comment: The **GetFace** method seems to be  the exact code needed here. Wondering why you have written that code and don't use it.

Comment: Your card class should include a Value property.  A Queen is a Queen, but its value is 10 instead of that `GetValue` method which is incorrect.  Next, your deck could put the shuffled cards in a `Stack<T>` which would allow them to be used up.  Also, most times a BJ shoe is made of more than one deck.

Comment: You should consider shuffling your deck instead of drawing a random card from it. Probably makes the rest of the code easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when I try to test the deck class the array is filled with `BlackJackLab.Deck`

It looks like all cards are the same, but they are not. In order to see what they are you should either write their rank and suit separately, or override `ToString` to see the values in the debugger as well:

```
public override string ToString() {
    return rank + " of " + suit;
}
```

Note that you could greatly simplify your validation code is you start using your static arrays of suits and ranks, like this:

```
public Card(string suit, string rank) {
    if (Array.IndexOf(ValidSuits(), suit) < 0) {
        throw new ArgumentException("suit");
    }
    ... // Do the same for the rank before assigning the fields
}
```

Rather than creating arrays of valid ranks and suits on the fly, you could pre-create these arrays statically, and then return them from your methods. Moreover, converting these methods to static properties would be an even better way to go:

```
private static string[] validSuits = new[] {
    "Hearts", "Spades", "Diamonds", "Clubs"
};
public string[] ValidSuits {
    get {
        return validSuits;
    }
}
```

Comment: So, is there a mistake in the current code and I just can't see the correct values in the debugger?

Comment: Thanks for your support btw ^^

Comment: @PanosKikas No, there is no mistake in the current code, it's just that you cannot see the correct values in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct answer to your question. I just thought that you might like to see a refactoring of your code.

```
public class Card
{
    public string Suit { get; private set; }
    public string Rank { get; private set; }

    public Card(string suit, string rank)
    {
        if (!(ValidSuits().Contains(suit) && ValidRanks().Contains(rank)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error not such suit or rank found. Exiting...");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }
        else
        {
            this.Suit = suit;
            this.Rank = rank;
        }
    }

    public static string[] ValidSuits()
    {
        return new [] { "Hearts", "Spades", "Diamonds", "Clubs", };
    }

    public static string[] ValidRanks()
    {
        var named = new [] { "Ace", "Jack", "Queen", "King" };
        return named.Take(1).Concat(Enumerable.Range(2, 9).Select(n => n.ToString())).Concat(named.Skip(1)).ToArray();
    }

    public int GetValue()
    {
        return Array.IndexOf(ValidRanks(), this.Rank) + 1;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0} of {1}", this.Rank, this.Suit);
    }
}

public class Deck
{
    public Card[] Cards { get; set; }
    private Random RandomGenerator = new Random();

    public Deck()
    {
        this.Cards = 
        (
            from rank1 in Card.ValidRanks()
            from suit1 in Card.ValidSuits()
            select new Card(suit1, rank1)
        ).ToArray();
    }

    public void Shuffle()
    {
        this.Cards = this.Cards.OrderBy(x => RandomGenerator.Next()).ToArray();
    }
}
```